# get an array of data-val values from a list of elements of a certain css class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get an array of the values from the data-val attributes of `.my-li` elements

```
<ul id="stuff">
<li class='my-li' data-val='1'>
<li class='my-li' data-val='2'>
<li class='my-li' data-val='3'>
<li class='my-li' data-val='4'>
<li class='my-li' data-val='5'>
<ul>
```

here the result should be [1,2,3,4,5];

anybody knows a good way of doing this ?

Comment: That's an HTML class. There is no such thing as a CSS class. (There are class selectors, selectors, rules, rule-sets, and properties that people has mistakenly referred to as classes though)

Comment: @Quentin look here http://www.tizag.com/cssT/class.php "Css Class", also if you google it you'll see lots of "css class" usages, even in asp.net web-forms all controls have a CssClass property

Comment: — Lots of people using a non-standard term with multiple meanings does not make it a useful term to use. I've come across Tizag a few times and never seen anything that that wasn't dreadful, it might even be worse then W3Schools and that is saying something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var foo = $('#stuff .my-li').map(function () {
  return $(this).data('val');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this simple one.

```
var array = [];
$('.my-li').each(function(){
array.push($(this).attr('data-val'));
});
alert(array);
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pp5pw/

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = $('#stuff .my-li').map(function () {
   return $(this).attr('data-val');
});

console.log(foo[0])
```

jsfiddle goes to http://jsfiddle.net/granjoy/KxQAr/